# Compare two dataframe in pyspark and change column value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two pyspark dataframes like this:
df1:

```
|language|users_count|
+--------+-----------+
|    Java|      20000|
|  Python|     100000|
|   Scala|       3000|
+--------+-----------+
```

df2:

```
+------------+---+
|src_language|abb|
+------------+---+
|        Java|  J|
|      Python|  P|
|       Scala|  S|
+------------+---+
```

I want to compare these two dataframes and replace the column value in `df1` with abb in df2. So the output will be:

```
|language|users_count|
+--------+-----------+
|    J   |      20000|
|    P   |     100000|
|    S   |       3000|
+--------+-----------+
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can simply join two dataframes based on common column values. in this case language and src_language and in the joined dataframe you can rename the abb column as language.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply join the two dataframes and then simply rename the column name to get the required output.

```
#Sample Data :
 
columns = ['language','users_count']
data = [("Java","20000"), ("Python","100000"), ("Scala","3000")]
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
df = rdd.toDF(columns)

columns1 = ['src_language','abb']
data1 = [("Java","J"), ("Python","P"), ("Scala","S")]
rdd1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data1)
df1 = rdd1.toDF(columns1)

#Joining dataframes and doing required transformation

df2 = df.join(df1, df.language == df1.src_language,"inner").select("abb","users_count").withColumnRenamed("abb","language")
```

Once you perform show or display on the dataframe you can see the output as below :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with `join` - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join

#### Data Preparation

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""language,users_count
                Java,20000
                Python,100000
                Scala,3000
        """)
    ,delimiter=','
)

    
df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""src_language,abb
  Java,J
  Python,P
  Scala,S
  """)
    ,delimiter=','
)


sparkDF1 = sql.createDataFrame(df1)
sparkDF2 = sql.createDataFrame(df2)

sparkDF1.show(truncate=False)

+----------------------+-----------+
|language              |users_count|
+----------------------+-----------+
|                Java  |20000      |
|                Python|100000     |
|                Scala |3000       |
+----------------------+-----------+

sparkDF2.show()

+------------+---+
|src_language|abb|
+------------+---+
|        Java|  J|
|      Python|  P|
|       Scala|  S|
+------------+---+
```

#### Join

```
finalDF = sparkDF1.join(sparkDF2
                       ,F.trim(sparkDF1['language']) == F.trim(sparkDF2['src_language'])
                       ,'inner'
          ).select(sparkDF2['abb'].alias('language')
                   ,sparkDF1['users_count']
          )

finalDF.show(truncate=False)

+--------+-----------+
|language|users_count|
+--------+-----------+
|S       |3000       |
|P       |100000     |
|J       |20000      |
+--------+-----------+
```